# What can I do with 500 ml of demi glace?

Tags: sauce, culinary-uses, braising

I bought a 500 mL package of frozen demi glace in my local restaurant. While I often cook with regular chicken or beef stock, I have never used demi glace before.

In what types of preparations or recipes would I be able to get the best use out of this - i.e. for which 500 mL of demi glace is enough and the benefits from using it over regular beef stock are evident? Preferably something that I normally wouldn't be able to make without demi glace.

Comment: Hi VoY; recipe requests are off topic here, although I think there's enough substance to this question to rephrase it as a "know your ingredients" type of question, so I've edited some of the language and tags.

Comment: Thanks, Aaronut. I think this even reflects better how I actually wanted to ask my question :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make some very good sauces, based on demi-glace.

- Bordelaise (if you add chopped shallots, red wine and a bit of marrow) (eat it with grilled beef, steak or pork)
- Robert (if you add chopped onions, vinegar and white wine, and a bit of mustard) (fits very well with grilled pork)
- Zingara (chop ham, mushrooms and truffle into tiny pieces) (You can mix this with tomato sauce and it goes well with beef tongue)

If you want to use demi-glace as it is, it fits very well with pork chops or lamb, hogget, or mutton.